# How can I disable Chrome experimental option same-site-by-default-cookies in Java Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to disable Chrome experimental option `same-site-by-default-cookies` and `cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure`.

From [How to set Chrome experimental option same-site-by-default-cookie in python selenium - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787776/how-to-set-chrome-experimental-option-same-site-by-default-cookie-in-python-sele), I know how I can enable, but what should I do if I want to disable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable by using `same-site-by-default-cookies@2` & `cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure@2`. Tested on Version 80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> chromeLocalStatePrefs = new HashMap<>();
List<String> experimentalFlags = new ArrayList<>();
experimentalFlags.add("same-site-by-default-cookies@2");
experimentalFlags.add("cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure@2");
chromeLocalStatePrefs.put("browser.enabled_labs_experiments", experimentalFlags);
options.setExperimentalOption("localState", chromeLocalStatePrefs);
```

Comment: Can this be done from the command line?  That would be especially useful.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone needs to implement it in C#:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
var experimentalFlags = new List<string>();
experimentalFlags.Add("same-site-by-default-cookies@2");
experimentalFlags.Add("cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure@2");
chromeOptions.AddLocalStatePreference("browser.enabled_labs_experiments", 
    experimentalFlags);
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified above for Ruby + capybara as below

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
    args:
      [
        "disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "disable-infobars",
        "disable-notifications",
        "disable-plugins",
        "disable-save-password-bubble",
        "enable-automation",
        "no-sandbox",
        "start-maximized",
        "window-size=1024,768"
      ],
    options: {"localState" => { "browser.enabled_labs_experiments" => ['same-site-by-default-cookies@2','cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure@2'] }}
  )
```